# Get dupticate node from xml file windows phone

Tags: linq-to-xml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

```
<top>
    <level1>
        <number>1</number>
    </level1>

    <level2>
        <number1>2</number>
        <number1>3</number>
    </level2>
</top>
```

i know how to get number if it single :

```
int levels = Convert.ToInt32(xdoc.Descendants("level1")
                                 .Single().Element("number").Value);
```

but when i have dupticate number in level2, i don't know how to get both number1 and number2 ( of course, the code for the same if i have number3, number4 or more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var levels = (xdoc.Descendants("level1")
                  .Elements("number1")
                  .Select(e => (int)e)).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of integers. If you want an array instead use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your code. I was used this code but when i show levels by messagebox, i just see 1 item is : "23" in array[0]. And "ToList" is the same. Can i see 2 items with "foreach" command ? And how can i do it for the Attributes of node ?

My code is :

MessageBox.Show(levels[0].ToString());